# Valgrind check for memory leak in C

Tags: c, matlab, memory-leaks, valgrind

We have programed a suite of codes in C which takes Matlab data files (.mat) in a dir as input, and it also calls GSL functions to search for the roots of a polynormial and generate random numbers as such. We are working on OSX. We used `Valgrind` to check if there are any memory leaks since we used quite lots of `malloc` and `free` in the codes. And it indeed helped us a lot in finding memory leaks at many places. However, there are still one that we cannot fix. The problem exists in the function `listfileswext`(it lists all files in a directory with a given extension, i.e. `.mat`) in the subroutine called `maxphaseutils.c`:

```
char ** listfileswext (const char *ext, const char *dirName, size_t *nFiles, size_t *maxFileNameLen)
{
    /*printf("------- %s -------\n",ext);
    printf("Extension string length %zu\n",strlen(ext));*/
  char *pattern = (char *)malloc((3+strlen(ext))*sizeof(char));
  DIR *dp;
  struct dirent *ep;
  char **fileList;
  size_t lpc;

  pattern[0] = '*';
  pattern[1] = '.';
  pattern[2] = '\0';
  strcat(pattern,ext);

  /*printf("Pattern %s\n",pattern);*/
  /* Step 1: Count the number of files with the required 
     extension.
  */
  size_t countValidFiles = 0;
  dp = opendir(dirName);
  if (dp != NULL){
      while ((ep = readdir(dp))){
            /*printf("Checking file %s\n",ep->d_name);*/
            if(!fnmatch(pattern, ep->d_name, (FNM_FILE_NAME|FNM_PERIOD))){
                /* Match. Increment counter */
                /*printf("found match with pattern %s\n",pattern);*/
                countValidFiles++;
            }
      }
      (void) closedir (dp);
      /*
        Apparently, there is no need to free ep as it is declared to be 'static' in the readdir function
      */
  }
  else{
    printf ("Couldn't open the directory %s\n",dirName);
    free(pattern);
    return NULL;
  }
  *nFiles = countValidFiles;
  /* Step 2: Create storage for list of filenames */
  fileList = (char **)malloc(countValidFiles*sizeof(char *));
  /* Can't find a better way than to repeat the whole loop again */
  countValidFiles = 0;
  dp = opendir(dirName);
  if (dp != NULL){
      while ((ep = readdir(dp))){
            if(!fnmatch(pattern, ep->d_name, (FNM_FILE_NAME|FNM_PERIOD))){
                fileList[countValidFiles] = (char *)malloc(strlen(ep->d_name)*sizeof(char));
                strcpy(fileList[countValidFiles],ep->d_name);
                /* Match. Increment counter */
                countValidFiles++;
            }
      }
      (void) closedir (dp);
  }
  else{
    printf ("Couldn't open the directory %s\n",dirName);
    return NULL;
  }

    /*Find longest filename */
    size_t fileNameLen;
    *maxFileNameLen = 0;
    size_t lpc1;
    for (lpc1 = 0; lpc1 < *nFiles; lpc1++){
        fileNameLen = strlen(fileList[lpc1]);
        if ( fileNameLen > *maxFileNameLen)
            *maxFileNameLen = fileNameLen;
    }

  /* Wrap up */
  free(pattern);
  return fileList;
}
```

In this function, the variable `fileList` is called

```
char **inputFileList;
    size_t nInputFiles, maxFileNameLen;
    inputFileList = listfileswext("mat", simDataDir, &nInputFiles, &maxFileNameLen);
```

and then freed

```
for(lpc1 = 0; lpc1 < nInputFiles; lpc1++){
        /* Free up dynamically allocated memory for file list*/
        free(inputFileList[lpc1]);
    }
    /* Free up dynamically allocated memory */
free(inputFileList);
```

in main function as shown above. As you can see that `fileList` is freed as `inputFileList` in main rather than in the function (`listfileswext`) where is allocated. We think it's OK. After running `Valgrind`, it shows

```
==8643== Invalid write of size 8
==8643==    at 0x101921031: _platform_memmove$VARIANT$Unknown (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib)
==8643==    by 0x1016E33AD: stpcpy (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==8643==    by 0x101755F96: __strcpy_chk (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==8643==    by 0x1000044B2: listfileswext (maxphaseutils.c:153)
==8643==    by 0x100005FBD: main (perfeval_snglproc.c:41)
==8643==  Address 0x104c6381d is 13 bytes inside a block of size 20 alloc'd
==8643==    at 0x100010EBB: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:303)
==8643==    by 0x10000447C: listfileswext (maxphaseutils.c:152)
==8643==    by 0x100005FBD: main (c:41)
```

and

```
==8643== Invalid read of size 8
==8643==    at 0x101921040: _platform_memmove$VARIANT$Unknown (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib)
==8643==    by 0x101756127: __strcat_chk (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==8643==    by 0x1000060CE: main (perfeval_snglproc.c:67)
==8643==  Address 0x104c63224 is 4 bytes inside a block of size 11 alloc'd
==8643==    at 0x100010EBB: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:303)
==8643==    by 0x10000447C: listfileswext (maxphaseutils.c:152)
==8643==    by 0x100005FBD: main (perfeval_snglproc.c:41)
```

Here `perfeval_snglproc.c` is the main. Besides, there are bunch of staffs as follows which seem nothing to do with the functions we made (we may have no control on these system files):

```
==8643== 168 bytes in 7 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 657 of 1,081
==8643==    at 0x10001178B: malloc_zone_calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:717)
==8643==    by 0x1019C737C: NXHashInsert (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==8643==    by 0x1019C746F: _NXHashRehashToCapacity (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==8643==    by 0x1019C73B9: NXHashInsert (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==8643==    by 0x1019D6687: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==8643==    by 0x1019D5B53: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==8643==    by 0x1019CA38D: look_up_class (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==8643==    by 0x1019CA1B9: objc_getFutureClass (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==8643==    by 0x101D51D3F: __CFInitialize (in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation)
==8643==    by 0x7FFF5FC12BC7: ImageLoaderMachO::doImageInit(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==8643==    by 0x7FFF5FC12E8C: ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==8643==    by 0x7FFF5FC0F890: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==8643== 
==8643== 168 (32 direct, 136 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 658 of 1,081
==8643==    at 0x10001117C: malloc_zone_malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:305)
==8643==    by 0x101D6FF79: CFUniCharGetUnicodePropertyDataForPlane (in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation)
==8643==    by 0x101D6FEBE: CFUniCharGetNumberOfPlanesForUnicodePropertyData (in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation)
==8643==    by 0x101D6F9A3: __CFUniCharLoadDecompositionTable (in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation)
==8643==    by 0x101D6F048: CFUniCharDecompose (in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation)
==8643==    by 0x101D681CE: CFStringGetFileSystemRepresentation (in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation)
==8643==    by 0x101E91929: _CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath (in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation)
==8643==    by 0x101D693D9: _CFBundleCopyBundleURLForExecutableURL (in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation)
==8643==    by 0x101D63DE4: _CFBundleGetMainBundleAlreadyLocked (in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation)
==8643==    by 0x101D63D5A: CFBundleGetMainBundle (in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation)
==8643==    by 0x101D8C0A7: _CFPrefsGetCacheStringForBundleID (in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation)
==8643==    by 0x101EDADC8: __50+[CFPrefsSearchListSource withSnapshotSearchList:]_block_invoke (in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation)
```

Please help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16210408/valgrind-shows-memory-leak-on-empty-program-on-mac-osx-10-8), the leaks are not caused by your program, but by system libraries.

For the errors, when allocating space for c-string, you need to make space for trailing zero, so change

```
 fileList[countValidFiles] = (char *)malloc(strlen(ep->d_name)*sizeof(char));
```

to

```
 fileList[countValidFiles] = (char *)malloc((strlen(ep->d_name) + 1)*sizeof(char));
```

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1 **by definition** so you can omit those (see [C99 §6.5.3.4 number 3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf): _When applied to an operand that has type char, unsigned char, or signed char, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1._)

Comment: There are platforms where char has different size, look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098149/what-platforms-have-something-other-than-8-bit-char).

Comment: Yes, but `sizeof(char)` will also return 1 for platforms where `CHAR_BIT` > 8. That's because the sizes here are in _bytes_ and `CHAR_BIT` defines the _size of one byte_. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215445/are-there-machines-where-sizeofchar-1-or-at-least-char-bit-8?lq=1), [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437470/type-to-use-to-represent-a-byte-in-ansi-c89-90-c/437640#437640), [C FAQ entry](http://c-faq.com/charstring/wchar.html). So on a machine with `CHAR_BIT == 16`, `malloc(1)` would allocate at least 16 bits, `malloc(2)` at least 32 bits…